# How to read correct data from RS232 port

Tags: java, serial-port, port, rxtx

Please am new to reading data from serial ports.
I got below data from `Stat Fax® 303 Plus`.
What format is this? And how can I convert into proper readable format?

`99999999998?Z  8!  ~99999999998n<                      ~=0<                ~=0<                ~n<             ~=0n                ~=0>n               :*?^pZX             ~h/n8O:~        IN5yzI:jXKZ8nP      ~Z          I~-:7CF~*J  y99nZPXx~?X 8               ~XK         ~HK         ~XK)    I   ~hI1            ~I!         ~hIZ            ~_XZ0~~99999999998?Z    \C! ~99999999998n<`

I am using `jSSC` - java serial port communication library.
Please find portion of java code where I read from serial port below:

```
static class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if(event.isRXCHAR()){//If data is available               
                try {
                    String buffer = DataserialPort.readString();                      
                    System.out.println(buffer);

                }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);

                }

        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you may have the wrong baud rate/stop bits/etc, but only you know what you are expecting to see from the device at the other end of the cable.

Comment: Am able to get correct data with hyperterminal. Strangely my java code works well after I use the hyperterminal. Any one has an idea why the code works only after I try connecting to the serial port with hyperterminal?